# available package versions using apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Bit of a simple question but basically I need a specific version of a package to install inside a docker image. Issue is the default version that is downloading through apt is lower than I need.

When I check on `packages.ubuntu` (image is linux based) I can see the version I require but under a higher OS version, for example I am only seeing versions under `jammy` available to me through apt and need the version under `mantic`.

Are these versions only available if using a more current OS version? Is there a way around this? Any help or info on how this all works would be greatly appreciated.

For context the package in question is -
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=graphicsmagick&searchon=names